# Login Strategy in node.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm working in a project which has a social login (Facebook and G+). When the user create his account with a social network, I store the contact email but not a password. If the user want to use the local account, he has to recover the password. Is this a good strategy o I must to create a random password and give to the user by email?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to have it said: i really hope that you are storing passwords not in plain text (saying this, because when a service sends me a password in plain text, they usually do that...)

Comment: No, I use bcrypt to save the password in the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen it done two ways:

1. Use external logins to migrate user data across
2. Use external auth to actually perform the authentication (Safer)

for 1), you'll have to get the user to create their own password. Don't forget this is a non-trivial activity ([salt your hashes](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), use [bcrypt](http://codetheory.in/using-the-node-js-bcrypt-module-to-hash-and-safely-store-passwords/))

In the event that a user forgets their password, there's a few ways to implement a secure system, but a simple enough method is to create some [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) and email a link to the user with the nonce as an access url which should be unguessable:

ie: send email with login to `http://website.com/user/forgot/421c76d77563afa1914846b010bd164f395bd34c2102e5e99e0cb9cf173c1d87`

**Never** send the user their password. **You should not even be able to**, it should be one-way hashed and unretrievable. The only way it is used is to compare against a new login attempt's hash.

Regarding 2) 
Have a look at using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) or similar prebuilt module with OAuth2 integration. I don't think it should be the case that you need to store any password if you're authenticating externally. This is a good start option.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to jump in and make some recommendations slightly different than David (whose answer is great, by the way).

**NOTE**: I'm a bit biased because the library I'm recommending is the one I wrote: [express-stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/).

Basically, whenever you want to support multiple logins for users, you have various options. Some of it boils down to a choice of the UX experience you want to provide for your users.

For instance: do you want to *force* users to create a traditional account with email / password, and then let them selectively link their Facebook / Google accounts? Or do you want to do something a bit more custom?

One of the issues I've had doing the above stuff with Passport.js is that you have to use multiple strategies, which sometimes causes issues: you've got to do a lot of manual work yourself, and it takes a lot of time / trial / error.

Instead, for more complex situations like the above, I like using the express-stormpath stuff.

Here's a code sample which provides a registration page, and a login page with Google / Facebook / email account registration and verification. It does all of this magically by using your social credentials and generating the appropriate buttons / backend code to handle all OAuth negotiation 100%:

```
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

var app = express();

app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  enableFacebook: true,
  enableGoogle: true,
  social: {
    facebook: {
      appId: 'xxx',
      appSecret: 'xxx'
    },
    google: {
      clientId: 'xxx',
      clientSecret: 'xxx'
    }
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

The above is a full, working project. If you visit /register, you'll be prompted to create an account.

If you visit /login, you'll be prompted to log into an account (with email/password, facebook, or google).

Easy right?

If you'd like to learn more about how to setup the Facebook / Google login with express-stormpath, you can find info here:

- Facebook Guide: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/product.html#use-facebook-login
- Google Guide: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/product.html#use-google-login
- Normal quickstart docs: https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/setup.html

Good luck with your project.